# family wise error rate in highly dependent data

Tags: statistical-significance, multiple-comparisons, bonferroni

I was hoping someone could help with a problem in my area of Optometry.  We use visual fields/perimetry to assess patients visual function. This consists of patient responses (or not) to points of light projected onto various locations on the retina at various stimulus intensities. The dimmest light seen is recorded as the threshold sensitivity at that point.

Usually 40-60 separate points are tested across each patients retina and then the overall mean sensitivity is given as the average of all individual point sensitivities.

My question is this:

since the mean sensitivity consists of 40-60 individually tested points, should p-values associated with changes in the mean sensitivity value over time be adjusted?

Currently, no correction is applied in our profession as a whole and I'm now wondering if this is incorrect. If a retinal treatment is applied then several point sensitivities will increase (in a non-independent way) contributing to the overall mean sensitivity increasing, however, should the p-value of significant gain in mean sensitivity be adjusted by a factor of 40-60?

This is analagous to questions around p-value adjustment in a repeated measures design, except this isn't exactly repeated measures but separate points that are highly dependent on each other.

Thank you for any thoughts on this

[image: here is an example of the type of data I'm dealing with. Here an average is taken of all these individual points giving an overall mean sensitivity of 28 decibels]

Comment: Your question isn't clear to me. The end-point you are comparing is "mean sensitivity". But you are asking about adjusting for mean sensitivity. How can you adjust for the variable you are comparing? Please add more detail.

Comment: Hi Harvey, thanks for the response.  To try and clarify, the main change we are all interested in is in the "mean sensitivity" and p-values are calculated based on changes in this "mean sensitivity " metric.  My confusion is whether you can rely on this p-value given that the "mean sensitivity" is not a single independent measure but rather an average of a collection of individually tested points.

Comment: That makes sense. The keywords to search for are "nested design" or "hierarchical design' (the latter is more general. "Multilevel" is another one. Not something I can help with much, but pointing out the right terms to search for may be all the help you need.

Comment: Thank you. I can't see a satisfactory answer to this question on any searches. I perform linear mixed effects models frequently but this isn't exactly a nested or repeated measures problem as far as I can see.  The closest analogy I can think of would be how to deal with statistics and p values associated with BMI given that BMI is calculated from two properties , height and weight. As there's two measures that make up BMI do you need to correct for possible family wise errors with something like bonferroni?  I've asked this specific example as a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

So in response to my own question and after a small discussion on a variation on this problem posted here:

[Statistics of BMI](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/619191/statistics-of-bmi/619195?noredirect=1#comment1151300_619195)

I think I finally understand when familywise error rates are a problem that need addressing (using Bonferroni or similar).  In my example above, even though the average sensitivity is comprised of averaging all the individual points, when performing statistics on the average sensitivities you do not need to correct for familywise error rates since, for the purposes of statistical analysis, the average value is a single independent measure in itself and not considered in terms of it's construct as a summary collection of individual points.

To me this was a rather subtle point. In my other post I asked a related question about statistics of BMI where (similar to this example of average sensitivity) the BMI index is a summary statistic which is not directly measured but rather calculated from two other direct measurements, height and weight.  I was confused as to why Bonferroni was not needed in the case of BMI being constructed from both height and weight measurements

As Whuber pointed out, my confusion was in conflating hypothesis testing with measurement tests.   The hypothesis test in that case was that BMI decreases with treatment X. Statistical tests on BMI do not need correcting for possible familywise error rates since the any p-values obtained regarding the effect of treatment X on BMI are derived from the dispersion of BMI data and resulting confidence intervals associated with BMI. As a result, a significant change in BMI tells you only about changes in BMI and NOT about significance of changes in height or in weight.

Hope this explanation makes sense to others. Perhaps this was obvious to most.