# BMI is calculated from two other measurements, so does it need adjusting for multiple comparisons?

Tags: multiple-comparisons, measurement-error, measurement

If BMI is calculated from measures of patient height as well has weight, do statistical tests and resulting p values around BMI changes need adjusting for multiple comparisons? I.e. Two tests were performed 1) height and 2) weight

Is a correction needed to account for possible family wise error rates from measuring two properties within a single patient?

I've never seen this mentioned in any papers about BMI. i.e. do compound metrics such as BMI or average values need adjusting to prevent familywise errors?

Comment: Please do not confuse a *measurement* with a *hypothesis test.*  It doesn't matter if BMI were derived from a million measurements: it's still *a single characteristic* of an individual.  (A million is no exaggeration, either: consider the evaluation of satellite photos, where sometimes billions of numbers are combined to produce a single characteristic of one photo.)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I'm still somewhat confused as I'm assuming (perhaps incorrectly here) that BMI is not an intrinsic characteristic of an individual but rather an artificial construct comprised of two other intrinsic characteristics. Hence twice the probability of a type 1 error.

Comment: Taken further, what if I wanted to see the effect of medication X on the 'fake' index where the 'fake' index is derived from an average of height, weight, sex, IQ, economic status, star sign  etc...

Comment: Yes, it is correct that you only need to adjust for multiple testing if you actually perform multiple tests to answer the same question. In your example, you could test if a medication affects height, weight, blood pressure, head ache, color of teeth, etc. Even if the medication has no effect whatsoever, you would on average have one test with $p$-value below 5% when doing 20 such tests, see https://xkcd.com/882/ :-)
-sorry I commented on an older comment of yours
If you only test the fake index, it does not matter. If you test all the different variables, you need to correct.

Comment: Thank you ute. It seems like you and whuber are in agreement so I am sure I am missing something crucial here.. but what's to stop a type 1 error occuring in my fake index when any one of 100 or 1000 measurements make up my fake index?

Comment: Ok, I think I understand whuber's point now. If my 'fake index' has increased after treatment X in a cohort then the p value associated with gain is simply a function of the confidence interval associated with the change. Any type 1 error would be a result of the probability of the true mean change of the fake index being outside of the 95% confidence intervals (for alpha=0.05). This calculation isn't concerned with who or what makes up my 'fake index'.

Comment: I'm assuming that if I make up a fake index for the sole purpose of detecting a significant change in one or more or the 1000 measurements that make up my 'fake index'  then this would be a form of p-hacking?

Comment: Coming back around to BMI, I suppose a significant change in BMI after taking medication X says that medication X is associated with a significant change in BMI only and says nothing about whether the significant change was in weight or in height.

Comment: Re "intrinsic:" If BMI is not "intrinsic," in whatever sense of the word you intend, then necessarily one or both of height or weight is not intrinsic, either!

Comment: by "intrinsic" I meant that you don't directly measure BMI.. it's a made up index calculated from direct measurements of height and weight where you divide one by the other but I understand your point and the fact that all of this is moot.. it's the hypothesis testing about whatever measure you want that is the relevant rather than what the metric represents.   Thank you Whuber.

Comment: Would it help conceptually if one *could* "directly measure" BMI? For instance, a gadget that created a detailed 3D model of the surface of a human body could do that.  It's also interesting to contemplate how indirect even measurements of mass (*via* weight or volume) and height can be (one might use LIDAR for a height measurement; or, for contractured patients one has to estimate lengths of curved portions of their bodies and sum those).

Comment: yes, I see your point.

Comment: I think @whuber is right that your use of the word "intrinsic" is confusing -perhaps it should be removed from the question? In fact [intrinsic and extrinsic properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intrinsic_and_extrinsic_properties) are a useful concept but they don't match the way you're using the term. Variables calculated from two or more other variables (e.g. density, speed, BMI) are often called **compound measures** - though I only found a few google hits where BMI was explicitly called this. I presume the opposite of compound is a "simple measure" but I've seen this less frequently

Comment: Thank you silverfish.  You are correct, I have edited the original post and added the term "compound" measure to hopefully clarify things for future readers.  Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

> BMI is calculated from two other measurements, so does it need adjusting for multiple comparisons?
>
> ...
>
> I.e. Two tests were performed 1) height and 2) weight

You have multiple measurements but you perform only *one test* with the statistic that results from the multiple measurements. So there is no need to correct for multiple comparisons (unless there are other ways that one makes multiple comparisons, but the multiple measurements is not a reason).

This is similar to this question: [Why is ANOVA not p-hacking?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/562984/)

---

#### Another issue with ratios

There can be problems with spurious correlations between ratios such as the ones described by Karl Pearson in

"Mathematical Contributions to the Theory of Evolution – On a Form of Spurious Correlation Which May Arise When Indices Are Used in the Measurement of Organs" https://doi.org/10.1098/rspl.1896.0076

---

A relevant element of the spurious correlation is that there is a use of two ratios that contain both the same measurement, for example "x/y and z/y" or "x/y and y/z".

In the case of BMI this can be any other measurement that relates to weight it height. For example consumed vitamins per weight.

Example: Let's test some causal model where the effect is zero, ie we sample random

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
W/L^2&=& \text{BMI [kg/m^2]} &\sim& N(\mu = 25,\sigma = 3)\\
S/W &=& \text{vitC/bodyweight [mg/kg]} &\sim& N(\mu = 1,\sigma = 0.2)\\
W&=& \text{weight [kg]} &\sim& N(\mu = 70,\sigma = 10)
\end{array}$$

So far the variables $W/L^2$ and $S/W$ will be unrelated. But now, let the weight be measured with some error, such that we do not observe $W$ but instead $W'$

$$W' = W + \epsilon \qquad \text{with} \quad \epsilon \sim N(\mu = 0, \sigma = 2)$$

and this measurement error will make us observe a correlation between the ratios because the errors of the two ratio variables become correlated. The correlation that we observe is not related to an underlying pattern in the deterministic part of the model, but related to the correlation in the random part of the model.

[image: example of spurious correlations with ratios]

R-code to generate the image:

```
set.seed(1)
n = 10^4

BMI = rnorm(n,25,3)
SW = rnorm(n,1,0.2)
W = rnorm(n,70,10)
epsilon = rnorm(n,0,2)
Wp = W + epsilon

L = sqrt(W/BMI)
S = SW*W

BMIp = Wp/L^2
SWp = S/Wp

cor(BMI,SW)
cor(BMIp,SWp)

mod1 = lm(SW ~ BMI)
mod2 = lm(SWp ~ BMIp)
summary(mod1)
summary(mod2)

plot(BMI,SW,
     xlab = "BMI \n [kg/m^2]", ylab = "vitamin c consumption per bodyweight \n [mg/kg]",
     pch  = 20, cex = 0.1, 
     main = "without measurement error")
lines(BMI, predict(mod1), col = 2)
text(14,0.3,"slope -0.00031 [p = 0.628]", col =2, cex = 0.85, pos = 4)


plot(BMIp,SWp, 
     xlab = "BMI \n [kg/m^2]", ylab = "vitamin c consumption per bodyweight \n [mg/kg]",
     pch = 20, cex = 0.1,main = "with measurement error")
lines(BMIp, predict(mod2), col = 2)

text(14,0.3,"slope -0.00213 [p = 0.000907]", col =2, cex = 0.85, pos = 4)
```

---

Sidenote: I would see this as the smallest problem with BMI. Already when BMI is used in comparisons without other ratios, then it might lead to problematic interpretations. The BMI is a very rough measure, but it is given a relatively large importance in popular scientific literature and advice about nutrition and lifestyle.

The arbitrary BMI boundary of 25 kg/m² for overweight versus normal weight (which originates around the time of the first publications from the [seven countries study](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven_Countries_Study)) is an example.

That boundary came from a rough binning of the BMI (like 20-25 and 25-30), but when the BMI is considered as a continuous variable a much more nuanced view emerges (the risk for several serious diseases is minimal around 25 or 26 but when considered as bins this disappeares and the relatively higher risk close to BMI 30 makes the entire bin look bad).

Comment: This question https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/562984/why-is-anova-not-p-hacking is exactly the same is my question just with more eloquence than mine. Thank you for highlighting this post.  I definitely now prefer thinking of the actual process of generating a p-value in conceptually explaining this issue. When you consider that p-values look at the distribution of data of the variable in question (BMI or other) then it doesn't matter what BMI represents, it's s still just a single measure.